# Performance issue due to more for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Because of the more "for" loops causing performance issue. It's taking 15-20secs to load the page. The first three for loops are getting from three different JSON files.

Code:

```
$scope.loading = function(item, scode) {
    item.calling = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.planMapping.length; i++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < $scope.callplanList.length; x++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < $scope.AHOfferScode.length; z++) {
          if (($scope.planMapping[i].PlanScode == $scope.callplanList[x].un_s_code) &&
              ($scope.callplanList[x].offer_type == "REC") &&
              ($scope.callplanList[x].s_code == $scope.AHOfferScode[z])
          ) {
            //console.log($scope.devicesList);
            for (var a = 0; a < $scope.callplanList[x].upfront_cost.length; a++) {
              item.calling.push($scope.callplanList[x]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there any replacement for "for" loop (filter or something) to improve the performance, something like:

```
euPlanDeviceScodes. PlanScode = CallPlan.un_s_code
availableHandsetOfferScodes = CallPlan.s_code
CallPlan.offer_type = “REC”
```

Comment: *replacement for "for" loop (filter or something) to improve the performance* No. `.filter` and other functions are there to make code more readable but they come at cost of performance. There is no function that can match/beat performance of `for`. My advice is try to improve algo. Like `$scope.callplanList[x].offer_type == "REC"` can be done before hand. That would reduce some iterations

Answer (score 1):

As commented before, array functions like `filter` are useful to improve readability but comes at a cost of performance. The difference is not much but still if you want performant code, `for` is the best option.

That said, you can improve the logic.

In your loop, you have a condition,

```
$scope.callplanList[x].offer_type == "REC"
```

This condition is not dependent on any looping variable and can be processed before looping

```js
$scope.loading = function(item, scode) {
    item.calling = [];

    var recOfferList = $scope.callplanList.filter((plan) => plan.offer_type === 'REC');

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.planMapping.length; i++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < recOfferList.length; x++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < $scope.AHOfferScode.length; z++) {
          if (($scope.planMapping[i].PlanScode == recOfferList[x].un_s_code) &&
              (recOfferList.s_code == $scope.AHOfferScode[z])
          ) {
            //console.log($scope.devicesList);
            for (var a = 0; a < recOfferList[x].upfront_cost.length; a++) {
              item.calling.push(recOfferList[x]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

---

Another place for optimization can be the innermost loop:

```js
for (var a = 0; a < $scope.callplanList[x].upfront_cost.length; a++) {
  item.calling.push($scope.callplanList[x]);
}
```

Above code is not using `a` anywhere in body. This can be replaced with

```js
item.calling = item.calling.concat(
  new Array.fill($scope.callplanList[x].upfront_cost.length)
  .fill($scope.callplanList[x])
)
```

Or if you can use ES6 features, may be `Array.from`

```js
item.calling = item.calling.concat(
  Array.from({
    length: $scope.callplanList[x].upfront_cost.length
  }, () => $scope.callplanList[x])
)
```

Comment: Can u plz confirm what is the word plan in the code var recOfferList = $scope.callplanList.filter((plan) => plan.offer_type === 'REC');

Comment: `plan` refers to `.callplanList[x]` in normal for loop

Answer (score 0):

Use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of using loop to check the if condition. It may restrict a loop

like,

```js
var array1= [1,2,3];
var array2= [3,4,5];
for(var i=0; i < array2.length;i++)
{
var matchedData = array1.find(function(x){ return x===array2[i]});
if(matchedData)
{
console.log(matchedData);
}
}
```

Now you can reduce one loop. as same logic do it.